# Unable to exit Guard when running on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, guard

When running guard on Windows with `bundle exec guard` with or without `-i` option, I'm unable to shut it down without closing the terminal window, it just hangs and doesn't respond to `Ctrl+C` and nor I can enter any commands when running without `-i`.

Comment: Related guard issue: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/385

Answer (score 3):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

I have the same issue with stopping Webrick and this also works for that.

Answer (score 0):

type exit :) This is how it is on OSX at least